# Is there a 3rd degree irreducible polynomial over Q[x], such that two of it's roots' (over C[x]) product equals the third root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

So we have a polynomial in the form: $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$, $a\neq 0$. And this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but is of course reducible over $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

We have the three roots: $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in(\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$. And we know that $\gamma=\alpha\cdot\beta=\alpha\beta$

So far, I have tried writing out the Vieta’s Formula:
$$-\frac{b}{a}=\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\alpha+\beta+\alpha\beta \\ 
\frac{c}{a}=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=\alpha\beta+\alpha^2\beta+\alpha\beta^2=\alpha\beta(1+\alpha+\beta)  \\
-\frac{d}{a}=\alpha\beta\gamma=\alpha^2\beta^2=(\alpha\beta)^2$$

I tried getting a contradiction from these but to no avail. Is there such a polynomial?

Answer (score 4):

If $\gamma=\alpha\beta$, then $-\frac da=\alpha\beta\gamma=\gamma^2$. This means $\gamma$ is a root of the irreducible *quadratic* polynomial $ax^2+d$. A root of a quadratic cannot also be a root of an irreducible cubic.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the last part? Why can't a root of a quadratic be a root of an irreducible cubic?

Comment: @MikMi4r68 Because any polynomial (with rational coefficients) that has $\gamma$ as a root must have $\gamma$'s minimal polynomial $ax^2+d$ as a factor.